# What does $f^+:=\max(f,0)$ and $f^-:=\max(-f,0)$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Let $f$ be a continious function over an intervall with
>   $f^+:=\max(f,0)$ and $f^-:=\max(-f,0)$

What does that mean graphically?

Comment: If you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the graph of $f^+$ is that of $f$ for the part of it lying above the $x$ axis, and the $x$ axis for the part of it lying below; $f^-$ is symmetrical.

Comment: But they do connect in $x=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $f^+$ is equal to

  - $f$ when $f$ is positive
  - $0$ when $f$ is negative
- $f^-$ is equal to

  - $-f$ when $f$ is negative
  - $0$ when $f$ is positive

when plotting $f^+$ and $f^-$ together you will get the same as if you were plotting
$g_1$ and $g_2$ with

- $g_1 = |f|$
- $g_2 = 0$

Comment: Thanks, Moritz!

Comment: Is $f$ continuous in $x=0$ then?

Comment: $f$ is definitely continuous in $x=0$ since that was stated in the question.
$f^+$ and $f^-$ are also continuous themselves so are $g_1$ and $g_2$.